# Drag and drop function making problems Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app in Swift. I wrote a`UIGravityBehavior`, a drag and drop function, and a collision detection between 3 buttons and the floor `UIImageView`, but when press on one of the buttons, the `UIGravityBehavior` for that button ceases to exist. A little help would be awesome.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
var animator:  UIDynamicAnimator?
var gravity: UIGravityBehavior?
var isRotating = false
var collision: UICollisionBehavior!
@IBOutlet var Ball1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Ball2: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Ball3: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Floor: UIImageView!

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!

    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    Ball1.center = location
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    Ball1.center = location
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)

    let gravity = UIGravityBehavior (items: [self.Ball1!, self.Ball2!, self.Ball3!])
    let direction = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1.0)
    gravity.gravityDirection = direction
    self.animator?.addBehavior(gravity)

    collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [ Ball1!, Ball2!, Ball3!])
    collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
     collision.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("Floor", fromPoint: CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, -7), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.width, -7))
    animator!.addBehavior(collision)
}
```

Comment: Are there any IBActions for the buttons? Setting any position or frame properties of a UIDynamicItem is not advised as it will fight with the UIDynamicAnimator. When you say: Ball1.center = location, you should use a UIAttachmentBehavior rather than setting the center directly.

Comment: I am new to coding, how do I use a UIAttachmentBehavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an attachment property like you done with your other behaviors. For example:

```
var attachment: UIAttachmentBehavior?
```

In your touchesBegan replace `Ball1.center = location` with

```
if CGRectContainsPoint(Ball1.frame,location)
{
    attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: Ball1, attachedToAnchor: location)
    animator!.addBehavior(attachment!)
}
if CGRectContainsPoint(Ball2.frame,location)
{
    attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: Ball2, attachedToAnchor: location)
    animator!.addBehavior(attachment!)
}
if CGRectContainsPoint(Ball3.frame,location)
{
    attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: Ball3, attachedToAnchor: location)
    animator!.addBehavior(attachment!)
}
```

Then in your `touchesMoved` replace `Ball1.center = location` with

```
if attachment != nil
{
    attachment!.anchorPoint = location
}
```

Then implement `touchesEnded`

```
if animator != nil && attachment != nil
{
    animator.removeBehavior(self.attachment!)
    self.attachment = nil
}
```

I would add the code you have, as written, will always cause Ball1 to follow the user's touch. Not sure if that's what you intend.

Comment: Its not, I posted a question on how to make the button draggable only if i press on it first, but I didn't get an answer I could understand.

Comment: I've edited the code to be closer to what you want, I think. There are probably better ways to achieve what you desire,  for example, you should look into gesture recognizers.

Comment: Hmm. when I ran the app, it crashed and I got an error in the animator.removeBehavior(self.attachment!) line of code that says "Thread 1: EXC_bad_instruction code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0", do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: I think we need to check if attachment is nil before that line.